# Merge realtime index and disk index

Tags: sphinx

I'm new to sphinx ( and full text searching in general ).
I've read that main+delta schemes are good for when you've got a large amount of data that doesn't change over time and some new data that is added.

So i have two indexes. One main index and one RT Index. The main index is indexed once using 
  `>indexer --merge index_main index_rt --rotate`
But i get this error
`FATAL: Failed to merge index index_rt to index_main: source index preload failed: failed to open C:\path\to\index\index_rt.sph
 ( No such file or directory )`

I'm guessing this is because real-time indexes are stored differently from disk indexes.
Is there a way to merge these indexes directly?

I may not need real time index updates. If so, Is it better to use a cron to update the delta index once every day and merge them weekly or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I dont think merging RT indexes is supported. They are already split into many parts.

Generally its a either/or, either use RT indexes, or use disk indexes (via main+delta).

If you want to use RT indexes, just have one big index - don't split into main+delta.

(Its no harder on the application, if you updating the small delta, using sphinxQL, you can just as easy update one big index)